# jQuery nth child

Tags: jquery, css

Is it possible to get jQuery to do the same job as nth:child(odd)?

So that I can add zebra lines to tables in browsers like IE6?

If so can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `:odd` selector to select odd table rows, like so:

```
$("tr:odd").css("background-color", "#DDD");
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong syntax: `$(":nth-child(odd)")` or shorter `$(":odd")`

http://api.jquery.com/odd-selector/

http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Answer (score 2):

```
$("tr:nth-child(odd)").addClass("odd_row");
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do ("table tr:odd") or ("table tr:even"). Try using http://api.jquery.com where most of these types of questions are answered.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.class:nth-child(odd)')...;
```

http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/